# How to import firebase into a module other than the app module?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, module, multi-module

I want to make a multi module app with separate Data module. Can I import firebase in a plain kotlin module, and if not, how should I modify my Data module to be able to import firebase into it?

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
  }
}
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
}
dependencies {
  def moduleDependencies = rootProject.ext.remoteDependencies
  def moduleTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.remoteTestDependencies

  implementation moduleDependencies.firestore
  implementation moduleDependencies.firestoreKtx
}
compileKotlin {
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my current build file inside my data module. Currently I am able to sync, and build, but I can't import firebase libraries inside the module.

Edit: The problem is that I want to use firestore inside a module other than the app module, but when I add the dependencies for it inside the data module, I can't use Firestore (because of unresolved reference)

Comment: What's the issue? Is there an error message?

Comment: Unresolved reference: firebase

Comment: The problem is that I can't import Firebase inside the data module of my app.

Comment: can you add the piece of code where you are using firebase...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to use firestore inside a pure kotlin library, to solve the problem I had to add:
`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`, and `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`, and an `android` block to the gradle file of the module. (Basically I had to convert my kotlin library to an android library)

Comment: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.library']
   > Cannot add a configuration with name 'lintClassPath' as a configuration with that name already exists.